# Android CardView implementation

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I created an Android app with list view. Whenever the an element is clicked, it passes intent to cardview.I have a  single cardview in my layout file, and use it for every element in the listView.

For each list item, I define different implementation for the CardView in Java passing intents from one java file to the other. .

Please is this a good practice using a single card view and Recycler View for multiple elements changing their text programmatically. I haven't seen anyone do something like that.

**Edit**
@Ankit something like ...

Something like

````
>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView/>
</LinearLayout>```



**Tutorial page 1**
       ```public class Lesson_Galaxy_One extends AppCompatActivity
{ super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.lesson_galaxy);

}```


**Tutorial 2**
       ```public class Lesson_Galaxy_Two extends AppCompatActivity
{ super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.lesson_galaxy);

}```

**Tutorial 3**
       ```public class Lesson_Galaxy_Three extends AppCompatActivity
{ super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.lesson_galaxy);

}```


Each with different elements for the RecyclerView's CardView with intents being passed from one to the other.
````

Comment: Can you please share the code for better understanding.

Comment: And for your question, yes it is totally normal to use single card view element for multiple list items or listview / recyclerviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There won't be any issues of using a single card view for multiple list items.It's totally fine .

Comment: Ok great, but please what about the text, I put it in Strings.xml, but since each of my implementation of the cardview contains many texts since it's a tutorial app. I realized most Android apps only use strings.xml for app name and menu item only.                 Please from any of Android experience, which is best way to put multiple texts (where to keep all the texts). I could put everything in the Java code but hard coding texts seems to be discouraged (even through I don't know how that is hard-coding since it doesn't ever change)

Comment: If your same text occur in so many places you can put it in the strings.xml file ,it's the best place to store them. There is no any hard rule of you should only put your app name and menu item in the string.xml file, simply you can place all your Strings in there rather than hard coding .

Comment: I am glad to here that @Mab